# How to cut individual data from an xml file using nodejs?

Tags: node.js, json, xml, parsing

I have an xml file containing data of 10 students. Each student details is bounded on a student tag. How can I retrieve individual data from the xml file using nodejs?

Comment: Did the you solve this?

Comment: yes@LucasHendren

Answer (score 0):

You have two options.  You can either use the build in fs library to read the file.  If no coding is specified you will get the raw Buffer you can read.

https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfile_path_options_callback

Additionally, to help out further you can use the xml2js library.
Example

```
const xml2js = require('xml2js');
const fs = require('fs');
const parser = new xml2js.Parser({ attrkey: "ATTR" });

// this example reads the file synchronously
// you can read it asynchronously also
let xml_string = fs.readFileSync("data.xml", "utf8");

parser.parseString(xml_string, function(error, result) {
    if(error === null) {
        console.log(result);
    }
    else {
        console.log(error);
    }
});
```

https://usefulangle.com/post/106/nodejs-read-xml

Then you can parse out based on the tags how you would like with the data downloaded.  I would look at the split function

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split

Let me know if this is helpful

Comment: I know this process. Im asking how to extract 1 data from the whole xml file

Comment: the above code will console all xml in string format

Comment: And you can use split to separate it out with str.split('your tag') and then you can select it by which one in the array it is.  After that, it deals with your data format which you haven't fully posted

Comment: If that works let me know and I can add it.  Youll need to post more on your data to get beyond that